# geting hidden sql id from a datagridview when clicked in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Hi I am trying to get the sql id from a datagridview in vb.net. I was already able to get the id from the datagrid when it is shown. However, this time i want to get the hidden unique id of the selected cell in the datagrid.

i got this code

```js
 If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
                    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
                    TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("UNIQUE_ID").Value.ToString

                    Try
                        connection.Open()
                        Dim sel As String
                        sel = "select * from ngp.ngpmain where UNIQUE_ID ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

                        com = New MySqlCommand(sel, connection)
                        reader = com.ExecuteReader
                        While reader.Read
                        
                            Add.TextBox7.Text = TextBox1.Text

                        End While

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    End Try
```

it gets the Unique ID of the cell in the datagrid only if the Unique Id is shown in the datagridview..I need it to get the Unique ID of the selected cell  and place it to a textbox even if the unique ID is not show in the datagridview.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try accessing the .DataSource property (a DataTable) of the DataGridView instead of the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` property to access the underlying `DataRow`:

```
If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
  Dim row As DataGridViewRow
  row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
  Dim drow As DataRow = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
  TextBox1.Text = drow("UNIQUE_ID").ToString
```

This code assumes you are binding the `DataGridView1.DataSource` to a `DataTable`, then you've set `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and manually defined the visible columns. `"UNIQUE_ID"` must be available in the bound data.